# Importing data from Sybase to MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm migrating an old Sybase database to a new MySQL db.
Since the moment that Sybase can export data to .dat files (something similar to new csv), I decided to use it.

The problem is that Sybase uses commas as column separator and commas in strings are ignored because are enclosed in '', but not in MySQL.

Is there a way to solve the problem? Here's my query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\UNLOAD\\166.dat'
INTO TABLE linea_col
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are enclosed by single quotes try this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\UNLOAD\\166.dat'
INTO TABLE linea_col
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

If that doesn't work then you should do `ENCLOSED BY ''''` but I'm 99.99% certain the first is correct.

Comment: Approved I was answering myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with how DAT files may differ to CSV, but you can use CSV as the common format.

You can export from Sybase using BCP and forcing the output to use CSV format

```
bcp database.dbo.tbl_name out c:\temp\output.csv -c -t, -U user_name -P password -S server_name
```

Then import into MySQL with

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```